# MySQL Expression in relation yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can I do an Expression in relation?

```
public function getInterval()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Notifies::className(), ['DATE(date_add)' => 'DATE(date_add)']);
  }
```

It does not work

```
public function getInterval()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Notifies::className(), [new \yii\db\Expression('DATE(date_add)') => new \yii\db\Expression('DATE(date_add)')]);
  }
```

It does't work either, illegal type error ;[

Comment: Your "date_add" column is it not date type ?

Comment: date_add column is datetime. But I want to get records by DATE (without time)

Comment: Doing this doesn't make much sense as the system would not know which attribute to use for populating the relations in the models that were retrieved.  If you only need to use this with single models, just create an ActiveQuery with a where clause.